# Hibernate : NullPointerException from HqlSqlWalker

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a web application, which has a search form, i need to find object with map that contains searched key,
I created this query to fetch all keys equal to my key :

CarDao.java :

```
public DatatableResult getList(Integer key)
    {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        DatatableResult result = new DatatableResult();

        try
        {
            BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
            JPAQuery<Car> query = new JPAQuery<>(em);

            where.and(qCar.map.containsKey(key));

            query.select(qCar);
            query.from(qCar);
            query.where(where);

            result.setData(query.fetch());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Car.java(Entity):

```
public class Car
{
\\Attributes
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<Integer, String>    map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

But i get this exception :

```
       : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3920)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone point out, where am I going wrong.

Comment: Can you check if this link is helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441407/hibernate-join-error-nullpointerexception-at-org-hibernate-hql-ast-hqlsqlwalker

Comment: @NageshTripathi thank you, but  i don't have a join in my case